# How to set OnClick in an image with View.setID(int id) programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

*Sorry if my english is not very good*

I'm doing a project(a memory card game) following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChrWz8ZMyOU 
I'm doing a little different
 I created a `menu_activity` that shows the name of the game and an image with the play icon 
This icon goes to the `level_activity`, here i have  three images that indicate the difficulty

The project don't show any error, it runs but at the moment i go to the `Level_Activity` and do click in the difficulty, the app doesn't do anything. I don't know a lot about this, but i think the problem is at the moment to implement OnClick. I try to create OnClick as i did with the principal menu:

```
public void goGame(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LevelActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

But when i did that when i did click in the difficulty the application closed 
And the LogCat show this:

```
05-22 20:17:20.578 12640-12640/com.mady.quimicamemoria E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.mady.quimicamemoria, PID: 12640
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mady.quimicamemoria/com.mady.quimicamemoria.EasyActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                         at com.mady.quimicamemoria.EasyActivity.onCreate(EasyActivity.java:39)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I show you the code.

LevelActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class LevelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level);
}
}
```

The XML of the image that indicates the difficulty

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/easylevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/facil"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             />
```

Class EasyActivity

```
public class EasyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener { 

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy);
```

//I skip the code that i  dont think affects the problem

```
for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < numColumns; c++){
            MemoryButton tempButton = new MemoryButton(this, r, c, 
buttonGraphics[buttonGraphicLocations[r * numColumns + c]]);
            tempButton.setId(View.generateViewId());
            tempButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            buttons[r * numColumns + c] = tempButton;
             gridLayout.addView(tempButton);
        }
    }
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {....}
```

In this case the LogCat shows this:

```
05-22 20:04:00.791 6042-6103/com.mady.quimicamemoria E/Surface: 
getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa0d6380
```

Comment: post your logcat showing the error

Comment: Have you initialized your button ?

Comment: @JohnJoe do you refer to the tempButton or the Difficulty Button?

Comment: Your onClick seems to be fine, I suggest you check this part of your code `MemoryButton tempButton = new MemoryButton(this, r, c, 
buttonGraphics[buttonGraphicLocations[r * numColumns + c]]);`. This part can give the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, which you are getting